# How to make a share and like buttons works in my tableview cell using Swift 3 , Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3

Would you please help me in my project.
I have TableView and in every cell have ImageView and TextView these data are coming from Backendless DataBase and two Buttons one for share and one for like could you please help me to make these tow Buttons work .

Ian using Backendless DataBase , This is the code that Iam using in my Project.

```
  import UIKit
  import Social
  import SDWebImage

   class NewsTable: UITableViewController {

  @IBOutlet var newstable: UITableView!

   var mydata = [TestTable]()
  let backendless = Backendless()

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    newstable.dataSource=self
   newstable.delegate=self

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    loaddatawithquery()
}


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mydata.count

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 if   let  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newscell") as? NewsCell{

           let ImgURL = URL(string : self.mydata[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].ImgURL!)
    let Desc = self.mydata[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].Desc!
    cell.textnews.text = Desc
    cell.imgnews.sd_setImage(with: ImgURL)

    return cell

}
else{

let cell = NewsCell()
let ImgURL = URL(string : self.mydata [(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].ImgURL)
let Desc = self.mydata[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].Desc

cell.imgnews.sd_setImage(with: ImgURL)

cell.textnews.text = Desc!


    cell.share.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.share.addTarget(self, action: #selector(NewsTable.shareBu(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)




return cell
}


  }
    func loaddatawithquery()

   {


    _ = "ImgURL"
    _ = "Desc"
    let dataQuery = BackendlessDataQuery()
    dataQuery.queryOptions.pageSize=50



    backendless.data.of(TestTable.ofClass()).find(dataQuery,response: {(result: BackendlessCollection?) -> Void in
        let data = result?.getCurrentPage()

        for obj in data! as! [TestTable] {

            self.mydata.append(obj)




            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        },
     error: { (fault: Fault?) -> Void in

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "انتباه", message:"يرجى الاتصال بالانترنيت", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { _ in

    let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "main") as! ViewController

 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
 })

   self.present(alert, animated: true){}


    })
}

@IBAction func shareBu(_ sender: AnyObject) {

   let myactivity = self.mydata[sender.tag]

    let firstActivity = "\(myactivity)"

    let activity : UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [firstActivity], applicationActivities: nil)

    self.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)




}


 }
```

Comment: Why have you set the button function to be an `IBAction`?

Comment: Iam just trying to make it works . Do you have a solution to make the buttons work ?

Comment: Remove the `@IBAction` and try. Put a break point inside the method and it should work (if it wasn't before)

Comment: I remove it but still not working . @Rikh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
cell.share.addTarget(self, action: #selector(NewsTable.shareBu(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

with this line of code

```
cell.share.addTarget(self, action: #selector(shareBu(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

as your method for selected is in the same class.

Also change

```
@IBAction func shareBu(_ sender: AnyObject) {
```

to this

```
func shareBu(_ sender: AnyObject) {
```

There is no requirement of using `@IBAction`

Also make sure your code in the else condition is getting called.

**Edit**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 let  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newscell") as? NewsCell{

           let ImgURL = URL(string : self.mydata[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].ImgURL!)
    let Desc = self.mydata[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].Desc!
    cell.textnews.text = Desc
    cell.imgnews.sd_setImage(with: ImgURL)
cell.share.tag = indexPath.row
     cell.share.addTarget(self, action: #selector(shareBu(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help Rajat but still not working . and I don't under stand what do you mean with (Also make sure your code in the else condition is getting called) .Would you explain more . Thanks @Rajat

Comment: Add a breakpoint where you are adding selector for your button and check is it getting called or not

Comment: No its not called .@Rajat

Comment: @ZaidMustafa edited my answer replace this method with your cellForRow method

Comment: Now its work but the share appears empty . No thing to share .@Rajat

Comment: I have done my job, you need to ask another question for that

Comment: @ZaidMustafa if any answer helps you then you need to accept that answer.

Comment: your answer helps me a lot thank you very much . I am new here in Stck could you tel me how to accept your answer?

Comment: @ZaidMustafa - there will be a tick mark near the answer you need to click on that - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: I click it thanks , and I made a mention for you in my new question could you help in it ? thanks